# HTML - Disable Roboform Password Manager

Tags: html, password-manager

I have an `input` element of type `password`, which is a part of a web-based game, and I need to disable password autofill to improve the UX.

I already disabled LastPass using `data-lpignore="true"`, but I can't find an equivalent solution for [Roboform](https://www.roboform.com/).

I also tried `autocomplete="off"` and `autocomplete="new-password"`. Both didn't work.

Is there a way to disable password autocomplete for Roboform using HTML or Javascript?

Comment: Roboform is a tool a customer is installing for himself to get some benefits. I do not think you - as a developer - can decline the usage of it.

Comment: I hate to be that guy but how does this improve ux? Is this field not for a a password?

Comment: It's a web-based riddle game. The password is an answer to a question, and will only be typed once. No point in saving it, auto-filling it, or auto-generating it.